# When I create containers in Cosmos DB with the Pulumi I received this error "'resource.partitionKey.paths' should be of type 'array' but got a string"

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, pulumi

I tried to create some containers on my Cosmos Db with the Pulumi from this [reference](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/documentdb/sqlresourcesqlcontainer/).

Regrading the above reference the Partition ID Input should be `String`.

[image]

My code is:

```
from pulumi_azure_native import documentdb

containers_name = {
    'mytest1': '/test1',
    'mytest2': '/test2',
    'mytest3': '/test3',
}

    # Create Containers
    for container in containers_name.keys():
        sql_api_resource_container = documentdb.SqlResourceSqlContainer('sql_api_resource_container',
                                                                        args=documentdb.SqlResourceSqlContainerArgs(
                                                                            account_name=cosmos_db.name,
                                                                            database_name=sql_api_resource_database.name,
                                                                            resource=documentdb.SqlContainerResourceArgs(
                                                                                id=container,
                                                                                partition_key=documentdb.ContainerPartitionKeyArgs(
                                                                                    kind='HASH',
                                                                                    paths=containers_name[container],
                                                                                ),
                                                                            ),
                                                                            resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
                                                                            container_name=container,
                                                                            location=location_name,
                                                                            tags=tags_group,
                                                                        ),
                                                                        )
```

But I received the below error:

```
 error: azure-native:documentdb:SqlResourceSqlContainer resource 'sql_api_resource_container' has a problem: 'resource.partitionKey.paths' should be of type 'array' but got a string
```

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/documentdb/sqlresourcesqlcontainer/#containerpartitionkey), the paths should be an array of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `paths` option an array:

```py
from pulumi_azure_native import documentdb

containers_name = {
    'mytest1': '/test1',
    'mytest2': '/test2',
    'mytest3': '/test3',
}

    # Create Containers
    for container in containers_name.keys():
        sql_api_resource_container = documentdb.SqlResourceSqlContainer('sql_api_resource_container',
                                                                        args=documentdb.SqlResourceSqlContainerArgs(
                                                                            account_name=cosmos_db.name,
                                                                            database_name=sql_api_resource_database.name,
                                                                            resource=documentdb.SqlContainerResourceArgs(
                                                                                id=container,
                                                                                partition_key=documentdb.ContainerPartitionKeyArgs(
                                                                                    kind='HASH',
                                                                                    paths=[containers_name[container]], # should be an array
                                                                                ),
                                                                            ),
                                                                            resource_group_name=resource_group_name,
                                                                            container_name=container,
                                                                            location=location_name,
                                                                            tags=tags_group,
                                                                        ),
```